# How to store objects which have relations in ElasticSearch (Search engine)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, search, search-engine, elasticsearch

I am going to use ElasticSearch for as the search repository in my application.
I have a few questions regarding what is best practice when it comes to organizing
objects in the search index when the objects have associations/relations to each other.

From what I know search indexes is a flat structure and doesn't work with the concept of 
relations in the same way as a database.

Let say you have these domain objects:

**Person**:
- Has a one-to-many relationship with *Car*

**Car**:
- Is owned by one *Person*, many-to-one with *Person*

**Department**:
- Each *Department* have many *People* and each *Person* may belong to many *Department*, many-to-many

What would be the best way to store this in the search index? What are the options? For instance I want to find all the people belonging to a certain deparment, or all people where the car has more than 300 bhp.
I am using the Java client API if it matters.

Comment: I'm not an expert (at least 6 hours experience with elastic search), so you are welcome to ignore me. You might take a look at the use of the 'parent' relationship to provide a little hierarchy to help with some basic normalization. Equally, dependent on your requirements, browsing through related documents interactively may be an option (since how many cars will one person have?). Just ideas, so let us know if any help.

Comment: I actually managed to get this working. What I have done is to use the nested type. It works very well.

Comment: LuckyLuke one quick question on your success, so I can learn a little more. Are you indexing individual documents or using the bulk index API? My concern is whether bulk indexing nested documents leads to duplicate Person document in your case. If you are indexing one by one then no worries.

Comment: I am doing both. I use the bulk API when I want to reindex the whole database, and the "normal" index API when I insert single items. I am not sure I understand what you mean by duplicated but I don't get duplicates. I have a IndexedPerson class which I serialize to JSON, and this contains all it needs about the cars and departments. This works because I have made the cars and departments as "nested type".

Comment: Thanks. That makes me feel happier about spending some time to try the nested documents.

Comment: I found this too: https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/blob/aaa3c48b3c105ed62acf5e7d2ad3a29866bbec13/src/test/java/org/elasticsearch/test/integration/nested/SimpleNestedTests.java It should give some hints on how to do things. Just go up in the hierachy of Github to see integration tests for everything. That should show its use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search (or Lucene) isn't a relational database, so you would need to *flatten* your relationship model.

Try to model a view that gets this structure -

```
Car|Person|Department
```

This will give you all attributes required to lookup a car. This can be imported into a document for `Car`.

Similarly

```
Person|Department
```

will give you all information for a person. This will help you lookup a `Person`

`Department` can be a third document.

You can have multiple documents for each entity. But the relationship needs to be translated as a property of the entity.

Comment: So do the car have an array of persons inlined? How is this done, is this what they call nested documents? Or doesn't it require any special treatment?

Comment: Yes, Car will have an array of persons. You could define `Person` field to be an [ArrayType](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/array-type.html) in a `Car`.